# Android/Eclipse Error - "Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, smack

This is my first time working with Android/Java. I am trying to run this basic code and I keep getting the following error:

**"Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method"**

- **My code:**

  ```
  package message.pack;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class ThesimpleigniteandroidActivity extends Activity {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

      }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                ConnectionConfiguration conf = new     ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.com",5222);
                XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(conf);
                    try {
                    connection.connect();
                    connection.login("myusername", "mypassword");
                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                            connection.disconnect();
                    }
                    }
                    }
  ```

I am using the smack.jar from this page:

http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-xmppjabber-chat-application-for.html?m=1

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: using smack.jar ? does it contain required class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is similar to many related problems surrounding External jars in android projects (especially with the new sdk tools). The solution is for you to create a folder in your project called `libs` and copy the jars into that folder.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the jar file in your eclipse path?

This will tell you how to do so:
[http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)