# how to add. JAR in my project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, buildpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

I found an interesting project to me, Wanted to use his library but I can not add to my library, as in the example

[image]

I do it in eclipse

**I can not add. Jar in my library**

[image]

Comment: What is the question and what is the prolem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click your project, select `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path...`. On the `Libraries` tab you can add the library.

If the JAR is contained in a project folder select `Add JARs...`. If you want to add it from the file system select `Add External JARs`.

Comment: @MaxUsanin It doesn't make a difference where it appears. Those `Android dependencies` are just a defined group of JARs.

Comment: Then ---> Could not find class 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions$Builder', referenced from method.... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions$Builder

Comment: yes you are right, how to fix it?

Comment: The jar is not packaged while the build. Try to create a lib folder in your project copy the jar into that folder and add it to the build path from there. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11003202/1568164  ... =)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project Build path is displayed, take mouse over build path other option is displayed then click on configure build path

A new windows open check libraries is displayed at top navigation

Click on the libraries

Click on add External jar button 
[image]
Browser your jar file

Add the file from the system.

Answer (score 1):

As Piotr said, I didn't understand the problem. However, here is how you can add a jar file in eclipse.

- Right-click on your project Build path -> Configure Build Path...
- Select Library tab There you can see on the right-hand side, Add
  JARs... or Add External JARs...

Select what do you want.

Comment: I've updated the post, right result?

Comment: Seems right. Appears any errors?

Comment: Yes appears, Could not find class 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions$Builder', referenced from method....  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions$Builder

Comment: Try to select the library, click Edit, click User Libraries, select library (again) and then Add JARs...(or External JARs...) UPDATE: As I can see you are trying to add a JAR file for an Android project. I am not familiar with Android but found this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3643015/1848025 Hope can help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jars and paste them into your lib directory for web applications

lib location :

```
YourProject
    --WebContent
       ---WEB-INF
             ---lib
```